# Is real part of a linear functional over a $\mathbb{C}$ linear?

Tags: functional-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $V$ be a  normed linear space over $\mathbb{C}$. I already know that if $h\in V^*$ with $h$ linear, then $h=g(x)-ig(ix)$ where $g(x)\in\mathbb{R}$ and $g$ is linear. This implies that $$f(x)=g(x)-ig(ix)=g(x)+g(x)$$

The last equality seems wrong.

**Final thoughts**

The conjugatión $\overline{f}(x):=\overline{f(x)}$
ensures the existence of unique $h(x),g(x)$ **real valued** functionals such that $f(x)=g(x)+ih(x)$. This is true for all functional $f$. But if $f$ is linear then $h=g(x)-ig(ix)$ and $g(x)$ is linear.

Comment: $h(x)=g(x)-ig(ix)$ where $g$ is **real linear**.  You cannot pull out $i$ from $g(ix)$.

Comment: Yeah, I just figuroed that. The conjugation of f ($\overline{f}$) isn't a mapping from linear functionals to linear functionals. Thanks.